# Django does not raise validation error username and password

Tags: django, django-forms

Django does not raise validation errors added to forms.py for username and password. It does bring up validation errors for password based on the core password validation, but will not check if passwords are the same. This is all based on the base User model in Django.

Can you help me figure out why the forms validation does not work? I get the following error is username is already in use or passwords do not match: "Form is not valid." The if statement if form.is_valid(): fails.

Forms.py:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username']

    def clean_password(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
        return password2

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        user_name = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if user_name.exists:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Username already exists. Please try again.")
        return username

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Views.py:

```
def payments(request):
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            password1 = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            #this works to do Django core validation, but not form validation
            try:
                validate_password(password1)
            except ValidationError as e:
                form.add_error('password1', e) # to be displayed with the field's errors
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            #this does not work
            try:
                validate_username(username)
            except ValidationError as e:
                form.add_error('username', e)
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = True
            user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            user.save()          
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Form is not valid. Try Again.")
            return render(request, 'next.html', {'form': form})

    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
return render(request, 'next.html', {'form': form})
```

Template

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Register now</h3>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p>Already have an account? <a href="{% url 'login' %}"> Login</a></p>
                        <form method="POST" class="post-form">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form }}
                            <div class="text-center mt-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Register</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: How are you rendering it in the template?

Comment: @Matthew added the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of that code is unnecessary. You should not be raising validation errors in your view; all the validation is already being done in the form. Your view should just be:

```
def payments(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            password1 = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = True
            user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            user.save()
            return redirect("/")
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'next.html', {'form': form}
```

and you can display any errors in the template via `{{ form.errors }}`.

Comment: This does not work for me. I added {{ form.errors }} under {{ form }} in the template. Instead, if I have two different passwords, it gives me the same " Form is not invalid"

Comment: There is no possible way for that to happen, as my code does not contain the part from your version that raises the error with that message.

Comment: Your right I had not removed that line. I'm still getting an error though: It never lets me add a new username. It says 'username already exists' regardless of what the username is.

Comment: In `clean_username`, `exists` is a method which you need to call: `if user_name.exists():`.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, I'm still having the same problem - the "same password error" never comes up and it goes to the next.html.

Comment: You don't have a field named `password` so the method `clean_password` will never be called. In any case, validation on more than one field should be done in the general `clean` method.

Comment: Can you explain to me what's wrong - I tried to add password to the fields, but it adds another box. How can I fix this in a good way? I accepted your answer :).

Comment: What don't you understand? The code to compare passwords belongs in `clean()`, not `clean_password()`.